# Can we make timer in alert using javascript?

Tags: javascript, timer, alert

I want to make an alert that has a timer in it,
the alert will show this message:

> Please wait to process data 3 second..
>
> Please wait to process data 2 second..
>
> Please wait to process data 1 second..

and if the timer is done, the text will change to:

> Succesfully process data..

I tried this one:

```
function countdown() {
    var seconds = 3;
    function tick() {
        var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
        seconds--;
        counter.innerHTML = "Please wait to process data " + String(seconds)+ " Second";
        if( seconds > 0 ) {
            setTimeout(tick, 1000);
        } else {
            alert("Succesfully process data");
        }
    }
    tick();
}

countdown();

<div id="results"></div>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

but this code will show the timer in div, not in alert. I tried to edit to make it show in alert but still can not figure it out.

Comment: I believe this to be a duplicate of [Display dynamic values in javascript alertbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186926/display-dynamic-values-in-javascript-alertbox).  If this is incorrect, please specify how it differs to better aid the community in answering your question.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Also, for what it is worth, I believe that ultimately the answer to this is that it is not possible.  You can look at the [MDN `window.alert()` reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) to see no such functionality is exposed.